# Conditionally executing a for loop I to count, and Count downto In delphi

Tags: delphi

I've got a function into which I pass a Boolean parameter. I'm executing some code which is identical in both cases, the boolean parameter will just determine the direction of the loop such as below:

```
If True then
begin
 for I:= 0 to Count do
 begin
   Execute a chunk of code
 end;
end
else
begin
  for Count downto 0 do
  begin
    Execute same chunk of code
  end;
end;
```

How can I write this a little more elegantly than duplicating the chunk of code to be executed inside the loops?

I'm very new to experimenting with programming, so go easy on me, and apologies for my terminiology

I've tried to search but either my terminology or my way of explaining is off as I couldn't find a similar help article.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent repeating the code by moving it into a separate function/procedure that you call, passing in the value of the loop counter.

```pascal
procedure ExecuteAChunkOfCode(const Index: Integer);
begin
  // Your chunk of code here
end;

procedure DoCountedOperation(const CountUp: Boolean);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if CountUp then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Count do
      ExecuteAChunkOfCode(i);
  end else
  begin
    for i := Count downto 0 do
      ExecuteChunkOfCode(i);
  end;
end;

// Forward loop
DoCountedOperation(True);

// Backward loop
DoCountedOperation(False);
```

Comment: You could take it a step further by making `ExecuteChunkOfCode` be a local function or an anonymous procedure

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You could do that, too. I don't know what version of Delphi the OP is using. :-) Thanks for fixing my stupid typo in my code.

Comment: You definitely can avoid having two loops, you just need to do some maths

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're right. An error in my phrasing. I've corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse loop by substracting I control value from loop size. Here is an example:

```
var OffsetItem: Integer;

for I:= 0 to Count do
begin
  //Normal loop
  if true then OffsetIndex := I
  //Reverse loop
  end else OffsetIndex := Count-I;
  //Execute a chunk of code using OffsetIndex instead of I;
end;
```

---

Alternately you can use [while loop](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#While_Statements) which gives you direct control on loop control variable so you can decide to increase or decrease it and by how much.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a mathematical style:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  system.Math;

procedure DoCountedOperationn(const CountUp: Boolean);
const
  COUNT = 10;
var
  i  : integer;
  si : TValueSign;
begin
  if CountUp then
    si := PositiveValue   //(+1)
  else
    si := NegativeValue;  //(-1)

  for i := Min(0, si * COUNT) to Max(0, si * COUNT) do
  begin
    writeln('ABS : ', ABS(i));
    writeln('SIGN: ', si * i);
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    writeln('++++++++++++++++++++');
    DoCountedOperationn(True);
    writeln('--------------------');
    DoCountedOperationn(false);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use 1 loop and use a separate variable to hold the "loop counter" that is incremented or decremented based on the desired "direction", eg:

```
var
  I, Counter: Integer;
begin
  if BoolParam then Counter := 0
  else Counter := Count;

  for I := 0 to Count do
  begin
    // Execute a chunk of code
    // using Counter as needed...

    if BoolParam then Inc(Counter)
    else Dec(Counter);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function iif(const ACondition: Boolean;
  const AIfTrue, AIfFalse: Integer): Integer; inline;
begin
  if ACondition then Result := AIfTrue
  else Result := AIfFalse;
end;

var
  I, Counter, NumToAdd: Integer;
begin
  Counter := iif(BoolParam, 0, Count);
  NumToAdd := iif(BoolParam, 1, -1);

  for I := 0 to Count do
  begin
    // Execute a chunk of code
    // using Counter as needed...

    Inc(Counter, NumToAdd);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You don't need to define your own iif function. This already exists as IfThen function in the System.Math unit, see https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Math.IfThen

Comment: @Matej True, but `System.Math` is also a *massive* unit, its overkill to pull it in just for 1 function.

Comment: Really? How did you decide that this was the only function in the entire program using Math unit? And so what if the unit is large. What's the downside?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't, but not every program uses `System.Math` (I've written very few that do). The downside is unnecessary exe bloat. For example, lots of people tend to avoid including `Vcl.Application` in console apps that don't need UI functionality, for this very reason.